# Select hive rows that contains specific character and 4 digits

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I need to select all the rows from a table with value for a column colA  has string  data like 'Pddd'  . ie if the column has data like P and 4 digits after that , I need to select that row.
I am using the below query . But it fails to pick the correct values.

```
select * from tableName where colA is not null and colA <> '' and colA like '%P[0-9]{4}%'
```

Comment: Attach expected output with mock data,  please

Answer (score 0):

Use `rlike`:

```
select *
from tableName
where colA rlike 'P[0-9]{4}';
```

You don't need the comparisons to `NULL` or `''` because they don't match the pattern.

Note that a regular expression finds a pattern anywhere in the string.  If you want a value that is exactly five characters of that format, use anchors:

```
where colA rlike '^P[0-9]{4}$';
```

Answer (score 0):

Got It ..

```
select * from tableName where colA is not null and colA <> '' and colA rlike '.*(P[0-9]{4}).*'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `like` there? Not `rlike`? And it seems `rlike 'P[0-9]{4}'` should work, too.

Comment: yes rlike is needed , missed that , updated the answer